# Match a word between two characters

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that should give back a true/false value.

Example:

> From: "johndoe@example.com" <johndoe@example.com>

I need to match the word **example** only between **:** and **<**, not *outside*

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly you are trying to do and in what language? In most cases, things like "replace this word inside quotes" are better handled with language-specific means.

Comment: pcre(php)
I'm trying the rules here: https://regex101.com/#pcre

Comment: i need to match a word inside quotes because i have an antispam product that could apply rules on headers and i need to match a word inside the quotes (this is a Display Name of an email)

Comment: Try just [`^From:\s*"[^\s@]*@\K[^"\s.]+`](https://regex101.com/r/dO5aZ7/1). Or do you need to find `example` as a literal? Then try [`^From:\s*"[^\s@]*@\Kexample`](https://regex101.com/r/dO5aZ7/2) or even `^From:\s*"[^\s@]*@\Kexample\b`

Comment: Not so far...
Probably it's better to match the word between : and <
And not just the domain, any word between

Comment: Like [`:\K[^<]*`](https://regex101.com/r/dO5aZ7/3)?

Comment: Probably i found the perfect solution: ^From:*[^<]*\K(?i)example

Comment: However, that regex does not meet your requirements in the question.

Comment: I changed idea on my original question... I need to find a word between : and <, case insensitive. And my last regex seems to be working.
Anyway, thank you because you pointed my mind in the right way ;-)

Comment: i've updated the original question, just to let other persons understand better what is the question and which is the right solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to *match* a specific substring after a known pattern that you do not want to be returned in the match, you can use the PCRE `\K` operator that omits all text matched so far.

You can use

```
^From:\s*"[^<"]*\Kexample
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eK8yA1/3)

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `From:` - literal sequence of chars `From:`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace
- `"` - a quote
- `[^<"]*` - 0+ chars other than `<` and `"`
- `\K` - omit the matched text
- `example` - match the word `example`.

You can further tweak the regex by adding case insensitive flags, etc.

Answer (score 0):

try this, you can test here: https://regex101.com/r/yQ1zQ7/2

```
\b\@(.*)?\.(.*)?"
```

(I've update to use with other domain name)

Comment: So, you will match `@` and `.com`

Comment: the first group is "example" the second it's the domain. you can test it in the regex101.com

Answer (score 0):

The below matches anything after @ and before . enclosed in quotes

> ".*@(.*?)\..*"